# Iwconfig Sensitivity Command / Roaming

Tags: drivers, wireless

I have a need to be able to modify the specific RSSI measurement at which my wireless client (Ubuntu) will roam. Referencing the iwconfig [manual page](http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/iwconfig8.html%20/), I learned that if my driver supports changing the sensitivity threshold, I can modify it to an arbitrary value (e.g. -80). However, my current wireless card does not support the "sens" command and has the following output when I attempt to set it:

> sudo iwconfig wlan1 sens -80
>
> Error for wireless request "Set Sensitivity" (8B08) :
> SET failed on device wlan1 ; Operation not supported.

Researching this error lead me to the conclusion that I can only modify the sensitivity of the roaming function if my wireless driver supports it (my current setup does not).

So my question is: Is there another way to modify the RSSI at which my client roams? If not, is there a confirmed wireless card/driver combo that will allow me to use this command?

Thanks!